# Boost property tree Bad path for nothing

Tags: c++, exception, boost, boost-propertytree

I am having trouble with this library... My code works fine, the parsers/creator works too, but an err appears, I don't know why:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include "journal.h"

unsigned short port                 = 2013;
unsigned short maxConnec            = 250;

unsigned short fPort()                 {return port;}
unsigned short fMaxConnec()            {return maxConnec;}

bool load(const std::string &file)
{
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree objectXML;
    std::cout << "bbb";
    read_xml(file, objectXML);
    std::cout << "aaa";
    if (file.length() == 0) // By the way, no way to do that better ? "if file doesn't exist..."
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        port                    = objectXML.get<unsigned short>("configuration.server.port");
        maxConnec            = objectXML.get<unsigned short>("configuration.server.maxConnections");
        return 1;
    }
}

bool save(const std::string &file)
{
    try
    {
        using boost::property_tree::ptree;
        ptree objectXML;
        objetXML.put("configuration.server.port", port);
        objetXML.put("configuration.server.maxConnections", maxConnec);
        write_xml(file, objectXML, std::locale(), boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<ptree::key_type>(' ', 4));
        return 1;
    }
    catch (std::exception e)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void generate()
{

    std::string file = "configuration.xml";
    try{
        if (!load(fichier))
        {
            save(file);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        load(file);
    }
}
```

Get a bad path, I totally don't know why because when I try to read data I can and it gets the data in `configuration.xml` even if I change it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ptree_bad_path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/ptree_bad_path.html) exception is raised from the throwing version of [`get`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#idp207933008-bb) and signals that `"configuration.server.port"` or `"configuration.server.maxConnections"` path to the **XML element** doesn't exist.

The error isn't related to the `configuration.xml` file path.

So you should check the element name or, for optional elements, use the [default-value / optional-value version of `get`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/accessing.html).

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I though when I just pressed the "post" button and I was feeling so sily, because I had to go. But anyway, that was it, thank you. In fact, I deleted some stuff to post, to make the code more readable, and it was configuration.time.save (I was looking for configuration.time.saving). Well again thank you anyway :).